# How to run cucumber, ruby scripts on iPad simulator

Tags: ruby, ipad, testing, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I have run cucumber+ruby+watir scripts on windows, now I want to run those on an iPad as well. Is there any way to do this?

Please tell the detailed procedure to do this.

Comment: if you are using watir classic (IE only) no.  If you are using watir-webdriver, see the answers below

Answer (score 1):

Try Appium: http://appium.io/

It it's a browser testing system designed for iOS and Android that should work for you.

Comment: Interesting, there are examples showing it used with webdriver via webdriver ruby hooks,  So really no reason you should not be able to use it with Watir-webdriver